# Changing the index name of an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have the following array:

```php
    array (
      'nurse' => 
      array (
        'skill' => ' gfgfgfdNurse Practitioner',
      ),
      'Nurse Practitioner' => 
      array (
        'skill' => ' gfgfgfdNurse Practitioner',
      ),
    )
```

I am trying to change the index name so that it is the same as the skill.
I am using a `foreach` loop to change the skill, but have been unable to figure out how to get the same change to index for the array.

Here is my code:

```php
    foreach ($job_titles as $jd => $index){
                $job_titles[$jd]['skill'] = "gfgfgfdNurse Practitioner";
            }
```

How do I change the index name?

Comment: the skill is an index of the nested array Nurse Practitioner & nurse, you can go back and try to access for them with the index of the parent array key

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```php
foreach ($job_titles as $jd => $index){
    $job_titles[$jd]['newKeyName'] =  $job_titles[$jd]['skill'];
    unset($job_titles[$jd]['skill']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing examples of the output would be great.

Any way, here are two different solutions producing two different results:

```
$arr1 = array_map(function($v){ return $v['skill']; }, $job_titles);

$arr2 = array_map('array_flip', $job_titles);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the index name but instead, you can add required index and remove the skill index. Try this code, Hope it helps.

```
foreach ($job_titles as $jd => $index){
      $job_titles[$jd]['gfgfgfdNurse Practitioner'] = 'gfgfgfdNurse Practitioner';
      unset($job_titles[$jd]['skill']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk` with `unset`

```
 array_walk($a, function(&$v, $k){
    $v['new'] = &$v['skill']; //Assign existing values to new index
    unset($v['skill']); // remove the existing index
 });
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/vf36W